# Error occured in Building a RESTful API using Jersey

Tags: java, rest, servlets

I am implementing a RESTful API using Jersey. Application is a messanger which is a kind of social media network which allow the user to pass messages, comment etc.
This is my code

Message.java

```
public class Message {

    private long messageId;
    private Date createdDte;
    private String message;
    private String sender;

    public void setMessageId(long messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public Message()
    {

    }

}
```

MessageResource.java

```
@Path("/messages")
public class MessagesResource {


    @GET
    @Path("/{messageId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Message getSingleMessage(@PathParam("messageId") long Id){
        return msgService.getSingleMessage(Id);

    }
```

When I run this through Postman Restful client it gives the following error

```
  HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception
```

Does anybody know the reason?
**UPDATED**

this is the service.java

```
public Message getSingleMessage(long uId)
    {
        return messages.get(uId);
    }
```

And this is the full stack trace

```
<h1>HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception</h1>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
            <p>
                <b>type</b> Exception report
            </p>
            <p>
                <b>message</b>
                <u>Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception</u>
            </p>
            <p>
                <b>description</b>
                <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u>
            </p>
            <p>
                <b>exception</b>
                <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
</pre>
            </p>
            <p>
                <b>root cause</b>
                <pre>org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public com.projects.api.messanger.model.Message com.projects.api.messanger.resource.MessagesResource.editMessage(long,com.projects.api.messanger.model.Message) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=PUT, consumedTypes=[application/json], producedTypes=[application/json], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.projects.api.messanger.resource.MessagesResource, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@6f3fd5b1]}, definitionMethod=public com.projects.api.messanger.model.Message com.projects.api.messanger.resource.MessagesResource.editMessage(long,com.projects.api.messanger.model.Message), parameters=[Parameter [type=long, source=messageId, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class com.projects.api.messanger.model.Message, source=null, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class com.projects.api.messanger.model.Message}, nameBindings=[]}']
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:555)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.&lt;init&gt;(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.&lt;init&gt;(WebComponent.java:392)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
</pre>
            </p>
            <p>
                <b>note</b>
                <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.68 logs.</u>
            </p>
            <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
                <h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.68</h3>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: No, because you don't post the reason. Post the entire stacktrace which you should be able to find in the server logs. And also post all the relevant code, in what you posted you don't even show where `msgService` is coming from.

Comment: also please share the configuration in web.xml

Comment: My **bet** is that your message should be annotated or some extra configuration should happen for your `Message` class to be marshaled into JSON. Are you using **Jackson** or **Gson** or anything else? If so, how are you using these?